# MySQL full text search matching similar results

Tags: mysql, search, search-engine

I'll try to explain my situation: I'm trying to create a search engine for products on my website, so when the user needs to find a product I need to show similar ones, here's an example.

**User searches:**
`assassins creed` OR `assassinscreed` OR `aSsAssIn's CreeD`  assuming there are no letters/numbers mispelling (those 3 queries should produce the same result)

**Expected results:**
`Assassin's Creed` AND `Assassin's Creed: Unity` AND `Assassin's Creed: Special Edition`

## What have I tried so far

- I have created a MySQL field for the search engine which contains a parsed name of the product (`Assassin's Creed: Unity -> assassinscreedunity`
- I parse the search query
- I search using MySQL's `INSTR()`

## My problem

I'm fine by using this, but I heard it can be slow when the number of rows increases, I've created a full-text index in my table, but I don't think it would help, so I need another solution.
Thanks for any answer, and ask me anything before downvoting.

Comment: Are you having performance problems or is it that you just 'heard it can be slow'?

Comment: @andy I've read somewhere, that it's the same as `LIKE` it goes through all records without using and index, so I think it will slow a lot when the number of rows increases.

Comment: How many rows exactly are you expecting? If you only have a table of  some hundred game names, you don't need to worry.

Comment: @andy many more, so going through all records is not my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should keep track of performance issues in your queries more precisely than 'heard it cand be slow' and 'think it would help'. One starting point may be the [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html).

If you have a table which contains the same parsed name in more than one row, consider [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database. In the specific case, store unique parsed names in one table, and only the id of the corresponding parsed name in the table you described in your question. This way, you only need to check the smaller table with unique names and can then quickly find all matching entries in the main table by id.

**Example:**

Consider the following table with your structure

```
 id | product_name        | rating
-----------------------------------
 1  | assassinscreedunity | 5
 2  | assassinscreedunity | 2
 3  | monkeyisland        | 3
 4  | monkeyisland        | 5
 5  | assassinscreedunity | 4
 6  | monkeyisland        | 4
```

you would have to scan all six entries to find relevant rows.

In contrast, consider two tables like this:

```
 id | p_id | rating
--------------------
 1  | 1    | 5
 2  | 1    | 2
 3  | 2    | 3
 4  | 2    | 5
 5  | 1    | 4
 6  | 2    | 4

 id | name
--------------------------
 1  | assassinscreedunity
 2  | monkeyisland
```

In this case, you only have to scan two entries (compared to six) and can then efficiently look up relevant rows using the integer id.

To further enhance the performance, you could extend the concept of a parsed name and use hashes. For example, you could calculate the SHA1-hash of your parsed name which is a 160 bit value. You can find entries in your database for this value very efficiently. To match substrings, you can add them to the second table as well. Since the hash only needs to computed once, you still can use the database to match by an integer. Another thing for you might be [fuzzy hashing](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/).

In addition, you should read up on the [Rabin–Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) or [string searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) in general.

Comment: It's not a matter of query speed, it's a matter of "what functions/methods can I use to get faster results (than with `INSTR()`) when I have something like 10000+ rows in order not to parse them one by one?". Having the same parsed name is not a problem as it will occur 3/4 times in the whole table, so it's not worth creating a separate table

Comment: @RomanHudylko Reducing the same parsed name to a single instance reduces the number of rows to search by 3-4 times as well! For the function part, I updated my answer.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to create a single instance for same name as the rows with the same name have different ids... As of your update: I don't think I understood completely how it is supposed to help me. I need to be able to find similar values too, that's why I'm using INSTR(), how am I supposed to work with SHA1-hash, could you give me an example?

Comment: @RomanHudylko It DOES make sense. I hope my last edit makes that clear.

Comment: @RomanHudylko First, your new solution does not even work for user input `assassinscreed` as mentioned in your question. Second, my answer is intentionally generic in order to suit a wide range of problems, including all imaginable from your question. Please either accept the answer or rephrase your question. However, I suggest you accept and open a new question since you are obviously searching for something entirely different.